# How to sort a column with Date and time values in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, rdd

Note:
I have this as a Dataframe in spark.
This Time/Date values constitute a single column in the Dataframe.

Input:

> 04-NOV-16 03.36.13.000000000 PM
>   06-NOV-15 03.42.21.000000000 PM
>   05-NOV-15 03.32.05.000000000 PM
>   06-NOV-15 03.32.14.000000000 AM

Expected Output:

```
05-NOV-15 03.32.05.000000000 PM
06-NOV-15 03.32.14.000000000 AM
06-NOV-15 03.42.21.000000000 PM
04-NOV-16 03.36.13.000000000 PM
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes. Tried Casting. It did not work out.

Comment: Scala. Since it was in string format, tried to cast it.

Comment: But it did not work out.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As this format is not standard, you need to use the unix_timestamp function to parse the string and convert into a timestamp type:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

// Example data
val df = Seq(
  Tuple1("04-NOV-16 03.36.13.000000000 PM"),
  Tuple1("06-NOV-15 03.42.21.000000000 PM"),
  Tuple1("05-NOV-15 03.32.05.000000000 PM"),
  Tuple1("06-NOV-15 03.32.14.000000000 AM")
).toDF("stringCol")

// Timestamp pattern found in string
val pattern = "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.S a"

// Creating new DataFrame and ordering
val newDF = df
  .withColumn("timestampCol", unix_timestamp(df("stringCol"), pattern).cast("timestamp"))
  .orderBy("timestampCol")

newDF.show(false)
```

Result:

```
+-------------------------------+---------------------+
|stringCol                      |timestampCol         |
+-------------------------------+---------------------+
|05-NOV-15 03.32.05.000000000 PM|2015-11-05 15:32:05.0|
|06-NOV-15 03.32.14.000000000 AM|2015-11-06 03:32:14.0|
|06-NOV-15 03.42.21.000000000 PM|2015-11-06 15:42:21.0|
|04-NOV-16 03.36.13.000000000 PM|2016-11-04 15:36:13.0|
+-------------------------------+---------------------+
```

More about the unix_timestamp and other utility functions can be found [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$).

For building the timestamp format, one can refer to the [SimpleDateFormatter docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

---

**Edit 1:** as said by pheeleeppoo, you could order directly by the expression, instead of creating a new column, assuming you want to keep only the string-typed column in your dataframe:

```scala
val newDF = df.orderBy(unix_timestamp(df("stringCol"), pattern).cast("timestamp"))
```

---

**Edit 2:** Please note that the precision of the unix_timestamp function is in seconds, so if the milliseconds are really important, an udf can be used:

```scala
def myUDF(p: String) = udf(
  (value: String) => {
    val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(p)
    val parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(value)
    new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime())
  }
)

val pattern = "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.S a"
val newDF = df.withColumn("timestampCol", myUDF(pattern)(df("stringCol"))).orderBy("timestampCol")
```

Comment: @Daniel de Paula: Thanks for the pattern for the above date format, but how this is working, even if the date has AM or PM?

Comment: @Shankar the lower-case "hh" in the pattern specifies that the hour should be between 0 and 12. Then, the last "a" in the pattern specifies that the parser will find "AM" or "PM" which will then define the correct time. Here's the doc for the pattern: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: @DanieldePaula: Thanks for the explanation, one more question, actually the converted timestamp is not showing the milliseconds properly, its always coming as 0, even if i change the input with some milliseconds, is it something expected one?

Comment: @Shankar The precision of the result of unix_timestamp is in seconds, so the miliseconds are truncated. If you really need the precision in miliseconds, you probably need an udf, or to convert the dataframe into a Dataset[String] so you can use map.

Comment: @DanieldePaula: Thanks, do you mean i can use DateTimeFormat pattern and convert the String to timestamp with milliseconds?

Comment: @Shankar yes, I will add a section for it in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use *sort* function after casting the *string* to a *timestamp*:

```
   df.sort(unix_timestamp(df("dateColumn"), "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.S a").cast("timestamp"))
     .show(false)
```

Comment: Virtually no difference from my answer. `orderBy` and `sort` are basically the same, with the difference that the first may be used in spark < 2.0. It would be more valuable as a comment to improve the other answer saying that the unix_timestamp function could be used directly inside orderBy, instead of using in `withColumn`.

Comment: It was my goal, actually.

Comment: Looks like the emphasis is on the **sort** function. Also, the pattern is incorrect, upper-case H is for 24-hour format.