# Date-Time sorting in Spark using Dataframes

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark, datetime

I am reading an *ASCII Text* file in Spark (Scala Language) that contains data in the following format:-

```
name|type|type_ver|id1|yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
name|type|type_ver|id2|yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
name|type|type_ver|id3|yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
name|type|type_ver||yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
```

I need to extract the type, typr_ver, id and timestamp columns from this and then sort the extracted entries according to the timestamp in descending order (latest timestamp comes on the top).

This is the function I'm using.

```
def parseTable(line: String): (String, String, String, String) = {
    val fields = line.split("\\|")
    val type = fields(1)
    val type_ver = fields(2)
    val id = fields(3)
    val timeStamp = fields(4)
    (type, type_ver, id, timeStamp)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    val conf = new SparkConf()
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    val spark = sqlContext.sparkSession

    import spark.implicits._

    var file = spark.read.textFile("/<path to file>/<filename>).repartition(10)
    val parseTables = file.map(parseTable).toDF
    val pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    
    val newDF = parseTables.orderBy(unix_timestamp(parseTables(x => x._4), pattern).cast("timeStamp"))

    val newTable = parseTables.coalesce(1)
    newTable.saveAsTextFile("/<path to save file>/Test_1")
```

This *[val newDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40655363/how-to-sort-a-column-with-date-and-time-values-in-spark)* solution was given on Stackoverflow itself that I was trying to implement in my code but wasn't able to. Also, the saveAsTextFile function stopped working because of this.

How do I sort the data according to the timestamp in descending order and save the output as a textfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Spark CSV reader to read the file into a dataframe, without manually parsing it. Then you can write out another csv file using Spark CSV writer.

```
val df = spark.read.option("delimiter", "|").csv("filename")
val df2 = df.orderBy(desc("_c4"))
df2.coalesce(1).write.option("delimiter", "|").csv("newfilename")
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad I forgot to mention that the file I'm reading is of 'ASCII Text' format. I tried reading it as csv with the "|" for split but it didn't work. With the mentioned file format will this work? I need to ask before trying it out because the dataset I'm working on is huge so I cannot afford to put this to test and tie up the cluster unless I'm certain.

Comment: @PixieDev csv is a text format, so it should work.

Comment: You can test it on the first 10 lines of the file if you want. That will save you some time.

Comment: Cool. I'm testing this out and will let you know in the comments here.

Comment: Just out of curiosity here, is there a way to do this without using dataframes at all?

Comment: Well, there should be, e.g. through RDDs, but it's easiest to use dataframes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228170/discussion-between-pixiedev-and-mck).